# Ruby Install JSON Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby, but receiving the following error, don't know what is causing the issue. 
I've installed Ruby 1.9.2, and using RVM on Mac OS Leopard.

Could not find multi_json (~> 1.0) amongst [actionmailer-3.1.1, actionpack-3.1.1.......uglifier-1.0.4] (Gem::LoadError)

I'm trying to isolate the error, but wondering should I run JSON (install) gem in localfile??

Answer (score 0):

Two things you should do.

- `gem install multi_json` from the command line.
- Go into your Gemfile for the project and add a line: `gem 'multi_json`. Then run `bundle install` from the command line